# How to get value from map and use it inside switch statement in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, switch-statement, constants

I have declared a map which stores enum value as a key and unsigned int as a value. I would like to use this value as a numeration for cases inside the switch statement. The problem is that the number which is specifying the case must be a const value. Method "at()" returns a const ref, so it cannot be used there. Here's my code:

```
enum KEYS { UP_ARROW, RIGHT_ARROW, DOWN_ARROW, LEFT_ARROW, ENTER, SPACE };
std::map<KEYS, unsigned int> steerage;
...
switch(input){
case steerage.at(KEYS::UP_ARROW): // does not compile
...
   break;
...
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to define your enum to have specific numeric values, like this: `enum KEYS { UP_ARROW= 123, RIGHT_ARROW=746, ...}`

Comment: Why not reversing `std::map` to `std::map<unsigned, KEYS>` and use `switch(steerage.at(input)) {`? Then you can use `enum` values as `case` labels. However, can't you use the proper constants of input directly (as suggested by @Yksisarvinen)?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the case statement expects a **compile time** constant. Here you are trying to use a run time value, i.e. a value stored in a map. That's why you get a compiler error.